# Take the average of the smallest 10 numbers of the last 20 entries

Tags: google-sheets

I am setting up a Golf index calculator and I need help taking the last 20 entries for an average. The formula is suppose to take the average of the smallest 10 numbers of the last 20 games played. So far all I have is:

```
average(small(i2:i21, 10))
```

I would not like to change the row numbers every time I put in a new entry.

Comment: =AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row()-1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-20,COLUMN())),SMALL(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row()-1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-20,COLUMN())),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))

Comment: In the above formula, you have to adjust row() and column() as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The `small` function returns **one** element from a range - in your case, the 10th smallest element, not the 10 smallest elements. This doesn't help much here. For your purpose, the combination of `sort` (sort in increasing or decreasing order) with `array_constrain` (keep only a given number of elements) works well.

```
=average(array_constrain(sort(array_constrain(sort(filter({I2:I, row(I2:I)}, len(I2:I)), 2, false), 20, 1)), 10, 1))
```

or with linebreaks

```
=average(
  array_constrain(
    sort(
      array_constrain(
        sort(
          filter({I2:I, row(I2:I)}, len(I2:I)),
        2, false), 
      20, 1)
    ),
  10, 1)
)
```

The array `{I2:I, row(I2:I)}` contains row numbers in the second column. Keeping only nonempty entries in I column, we sort by the row numbers in descending order. Then keep only the first 20 entries from I column. Sort again (by default: increasing), and keep 10 entries. Finally, average is taken.